# Unable to locate/click the element within iFrame (IE, Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, automated-tests

I have a problem to click the element that is within an iframe. Before this step, after clicking one button, a new window is opening and then I am switching to a new window and then I am trying to click the element within an iframe, however without any results. Here you can see the code:

```
@Test
public void test01() throws InterruptedException {

LoginPageMethods loginPage = new LoginPageMethods();
HomePageMethods homePage = new HomePageMethods();
ShoppingCartMethods shoppingCart = new ShoppingCartMethods();
loginPage.loginToWebsite(Recordset.userName, Recordset.webPassword);
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("The current window" + parentWindow);
homePage.goToShoppingCartPage();

//Return a set of window handle
ArrayList<String> windows = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
System.out.println(windows);
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));
System.out.println(windows.get(1));

//loginPage.loginToWebsite(Recordset.userName, Recordset.webPassword);

WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='contentAreaFrame']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
int iframecount = iframes.size();
System.out.println("Number of iframes: " + iframecount);
shoppingCart.goToSetValuesOptions();
shoppingCart.setCompanyCode();
```

[image]  (I want to click the Set Values Link)
[image] (inspected the element and this is visible - in Chrome)
[image] (ultimately I need to execute that in Internet Explorer and checked in here via the MRI tool and it didn't recognize the xpath, but in CHrome it does).

Here is what I get in the console:

> The current windowCDwindow-84EBD3BA474C418428AACFD82588EAF8
> [CDwindow-84EBD3BA474C418428AACFD82588EAF8,
> CDwindow-06F8C7313F9C0CF38B35BEA929AC2C0B]
> CDwindow-06F8C7313F9C0CF38B35BEA929AC2C0B Number of iframes: 3
> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Timed out after 30
> seconds. Unable to locate the element

Comment: You need to switch into respective iframe again after switching into new window

Comment: I am switching to the iframe after new window is opened

Comment: 1. are you sure you successfully switched to the next window? 2. the iframe locator is unique?  3. driver had enough time to identify the iframe before doing the switch?

Comment: Yes, the window is correct because I also did a check (driver.getWindowHandle() and it showed the second window which is correct). Also the iframe has a unique ID. I have an additional question. What is this iframe is within another iframe? Does it mean that I need to go from default content to 1st frame and then from 1st to 2nd one?

Comment: I agree with Narendra, you're most probably confused about you're managing your windows.

Comment: _Does it mean that I need to go from default content to 1st frame and then from 1st to 2nd one?_ First switch to default content and then move to new frame

Comment: Hello, I resolved the issue. The problem was the I was navigating directly to the 2nd iframe but this one was within another one. When I first switched to the 1st one and then to the 2nd one it worked.